# How do you trigger builds on remote servers in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

How do you trigger builds on remote servers in jenkins

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you can simply go to http://ip:port and run the build you want where IP and port is of the server where Jenkins is installed.

Please explain more if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

You can post an empty string to `http://jenkins.url.com/job/your_job_name/build` with optional authorization header.